# Proxy phantomjs through normal browser connection?

Tags: node.js, browser, phantomjs, same-origin-policy

Is it possible to proxy phantomJS through a browser (like chrome) connection? My use case is this: figure I have a server side phantom process that I'm running for a user but I would like to use the users machine to actually send the request (this way the users ip and headers are used.)

Is there some way to do this? Would this violate [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: unfortunately not. I think it's impossible due to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Node.js proxy https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy

Then forward requests to your phantom through selenium-node-webdriver

Then when the page finishes loading in phantom, return the source.

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/:sessionId/source

Not sure why you'd want to do this - unless you want to get screenshots server-side?